# g_file_new_for_path () causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, glib, gio

```
// gcc -o 0 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0) 1.c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GFile *f1 = NULL;
    f1 = g_file_new_for_path ("/home/user/1.txt");
    g_printf ("File loaded successfully.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program it causes segmentation fault at g_file_new_for_path ()(whether or not /home/user/1.txt exists).
Have I miswrote the code? Or is it a bug for my system?

P. S. : My system is Arch Linux, and GLib version is 2.28.8-1.

Comment: Can you run it through GDB and append a backtrace to your question?

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00000000 in ?? () (gdb) backtrace #0  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Comment: You need to make sure you have the `-g` flag specified when compiling (and it's easier if you disable optimizations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `g_type_init()` before using `g_file_new_for_path` -- as per [this thread](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=1296). After that, the program works.

Comment: As of newer versions of glib, `g_type_init()` is called automatically, and has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Firs of all you should use

```
// gcc -o 0 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gio-2.0) 1.c    
#include <gio/gio.h>
```

instead of

```
// gcc -o 0 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0) 1.c    
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

Then you should `g_type_init()` before of `g_file_new_for_path(...)`.